# Specify absolute position of GUI element in CN1

Tags: user-interface, layout, codenameone

How can I specify that a screen element (button, label, image, etc) appear in a specific location on the screen by pixel or relative position? For example the following hypothetical cases:

1. An element to be centered on pixel 350x 500y
2. An element to be placed 65% down the screen and 40% across from the left edge and take up 30% of the width of the screen.
3. An element B to be placed 25 pixels to the right of element A

I have watched several tutorial videos on the GUI builders & layout manager and read through several portions of the developers guide but cannot see how to do these seemingly basic tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do all of those using tools ranging from custom layout managers to just a bit of margin settings but most of those expectations are "wrong".

Placing things based on pixels or even dips doesn't make sense in mobile devices where the resolution/density can change radically e.g. your app needs to look good on an iPhone 3gs 320x480 or 480x320 (which will make option 1 irrelevant) and then it needs to look decent on an iPad pro 2732x2048 and the density difference is 3x meaning any standard pixel will look 3x smaller on the iPad pro!

You need to think in terms of dips (millimeters) for distance, not pixels. Then you need to change your perspective on positioning to think in logical not absolute terms e.g. words like centered, to the left of etc. work...

As to your points:

1. You can do this in many ways all of which are incorrect as they will break on the various devices. You can implement your own layout manager as [explained in the developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html). 
   You can also just use margin in pixels/millimeters to shift the component into position.
2. Same answer as 1 as margin supports percentage, millimeters and pixels. To determine width/height just override the `calcPreferredSize()` method but again that's a problematic notion as you might conflict with the fact that density changes image/font size considerably...
3. That's a valid use of margins although I would use something like 3-4 millimeters so it will look consistent across devices.

Comment: Thanks. I get your point as related to the widely varying screen sizes and resolutions. However, If one knows the dimensions of the screen, one may define a specific x,y position for an element to be placed at. Am I to take it then that the only way to do this is in CN1 without a custom layout manager is to use margins? Suppose an element is dynamically sized. The margin would be less useful as it specifies the location of the edge of an object as opposed to the center. We could calculate where the edge is based on the current size of the element If available but this feels a little kludgey.

Comment: "Suppose one knows the dimensions" could be phrased as "suppose Codename One was designed to support a totally different platform". We designed Codename One to make the sensible use cases easy but everything possible. Making X/Y positioning easy doesn't make sense for 99% of the use cases so making something that makes no sense "elegant" is not in the charter. Since Codename One was designed for mobile we dealt from day one with device rotation and the widely varying densities. Variable sizes is exactly why I explained you can't do absolute positioning so I don't get your comment.

Comment: FYI if you are tying to achieve a specific layout and are having an issue achieving it (thus trying to prototype it with absolute positions) I suggest reversing course and submitting a question covering the layout you are trying to achieve, e.g. I'm trying to do "this" (with this being a mockup/screenshot) layout in Codename One. How do I do that?

Comment: I guess that "makes no sense" depends on your perspective. I completely understand your argument against it, but there are some cases where it makes perfect sense. However, whether it makes sense is not the point of my question. We can discuss that in some other forum if the need arises. I simply needed to know if it was possible to place a form element at a specific xy position in CN1 and how to do it. It sounds like it may not be. If that is the case, I can deal with it and use another technique.

Comment: If I understood the point of your question you are complaining it isn't easy (you need to write a layout manager) not that it isn't possible... The question is problematic e.g.: "How do I do X?" instead of asking "How do I achieve Y?". That's problematic because I can't give "the right way to do is..." type of answer as I don't understand the end goal... Placing a component in an absolute X/Y coordinate makes no sense for us as a framework even if it makes sense for your use case. If we ever made that easy people would use it and complain when things fail on devices.

Comment: I'm not complaining that it isn't easy. I think you may have been trying to give a bigger answer than I was asking for. (And I do sincerely appreciate that effort.) I am working on a layout manager that looks like it will accomplish what I need. Thanks for your help!